# MPLAB X IDE v6.10, when i try to load my projects and open it. it gives an message "Loading" and the project doesnt open & the debugger is disabled

Tags: embedded, microchip, mplab, pic32

In MPLAB X IDE V6.10, Initally it is working fine. But after sometime when i tired to open project it is showing loading but project is not opening. And Uploading and Debugger option is disbale can't able to click and do upload the program.

Even Restarting the computer doesn't work. Any idea how to resolve this issue. I have attached to snippet for your reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxC5W.png)

debugger disabled: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t19nL.png)

I was working with project and tired to upload some example programs, after working for sometime it happened.

Thanks in advance kindly let us know how to resolve

Comment: Every version of MPLAB X breaks more things than it fixes, this has been proven more times than the Newton laws.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (same MPLAB X IDE version 6.10).
To resolve the issue you can clear the cache:

- in MPLAB X, click Help > About
- check and copy the 'Cache directory'
- close MPLAB
- open an explorer window and navigate to this directory
- clear the whole 'Cache' folder
- reopen MPLAB
- projects should be loading fine now

But I need to do this every time before I startup MPLAB. So if anyone has a permanent solution, I'm listening...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. However, MPLAB takes forever to load after that. Still exists in v6.15. Strangely not all my projects have this problem, just some.

Answer (score 0):

MPLAB PICkit 3, MPLAB ICD 3 and several on-board debuggers fail to connect in MPLAB X IDE v6.10. When attempting to connect to these tools through selection in Project Properties, clicking Apply or OK will generate the error

> “Failed to download firmware. Connection Failed”.

Fix: Install the MPLAB X IDE 6.10 patch. Do this by installing the 5 plugins suggested in the popup notification. These will enable MPLAB PICkit 3, MPLAB ICD 3, onboard debugging for certain eval boards and fix connectivity issues.

The 5 plugins are:

- PICkit3 Tool [1.0 -> 1.1]
- ICD3 Tool [1.0 -> 1.1]
- PK3OB [1.0 -> 1.1]
- PKOBSKDE [1.0 -> 1.1]
- MPLABComm [1.1 -> 1.2]

Also find the Plugins by selecting `Tools > Plugins > Updates`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and this is how I solved it.
My native language is not English, so please forgive me if it's a bit awkward. thank you google

It is believed that this problem is due to some kind of glitch in the system for saving and recalling project files.
Resolution:

1. Procedure to exit MPLAB X-IDE v6.10

   1. Close all open files before ending MPLAB X-IDE v6.10.
   2. Close all projects in progress before ending MPLAB X-IDE v6.10.
2. Procedure to start MPLAB X-IDE v6.10 anew

   1. MPLAB X-IDE v6.10 Start > File > Open Project > Go to ****.X from the top directory.
      Note: As soon as you start MPLAB X-IDE v6.10, if you open ****.X you will probably see "Loading...".
   2. If "Loading..." still appears after doing this, repeat from step 1 above.

I'm sure Microchip will fix this soon.